# JS Chart is displayed only once in php loop

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I have a script where many database entries should be displayed one below the other in a box. All PHP variables work perfectly in the PHP loop except the JavaScript code is only displayed once in the first box. In the other boxes I see only the empty div class.

How can I make each box show a different chart with its value, not only one?
Here is the rough code:

**index.php:**

```
<!--Other code-->


<?php
        
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user ='$user' ORDER BY date DESC";    
$results = $db->query($query);
    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){ 
    
?> 


<div class="accounts">  
<p>Name: <?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
<img class="icon" src="/icons/profile.png"> 

<div class="chart-box">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script> 

<div id="my-chart" class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>

</div>
</div>

<script> 

var data = {
  series: [
    {
      data: [<?=$row['value1']?>, <?=$row['value2']?>, <?=$row['value3']?>, <?=$row['value4']?>] 
    }
  ]
};


var options = {
  axisX: {
  }
};


var responsiveOptions = [
  ['screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1024px)', {
    showPoint: false,
    axisX: {
      labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
        return 'Week ' + value;
      }
    }
  }],
  ['screen and (max-width: 640px)', {
    showLine: false,
    axisX: {
      labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
        return 'W' + value;
      }
    }
  }]
];

new Chartist.Line('#my-chart', data, options, responsiveOptions);
   
</script> 



<?php    
}
?> 


<!--Other code-->
```

I have 4 users in the database, but the chart is only displayed for the first user in the first box.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, the you are targeting your each chart by the same id i.e., `id="my-chart"`,

and Id is unique for each tag. If you want to render chart for each user, try targeting it with **class** instead of **id** or you can can generate Unique id for each user, e.g,

`<div id="my-chart-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>`

and then target them by unique ids.